# Not all custom theme styles shown in ckeditor window

Tags: theming, 8, wysiwyg

In my theme.info.yml file I set my theme CSS to be also used in the ckeditor window. The problem is that in my CSS I declared some styles to be only applied within #content section, so it doesn't show in ckeditor. I tried these styles to be shown in the editor through classes like

```
.cke iframe body ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the mistake was to use classes outside the iframe. This way it works:

```
body.cke_editable ul {
 list-style-type: disc;
}
```